# FileOutputStream меняет байт `0A` на `0D 0A`

Tags: java, файлы

Я конвертирую `float` в `byte[]` следующим кодом:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(number).array();
```

Соответственно, если я конвертирую, например, число `0.02f` я получу байты `[60,-93,-41,10]`
Далее я пытаюсь записать полученные `byte[]` в файл следующим кодом:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(bytes);
dbf.close();
```

На большинстве платформ полученный файл в HEX-редакторе выглядит так: `3C A3 D7 0A`. Но на одном из устройств вместо требуемых 4 байт я получаю 5: `3C A3 D7 0D 0A`. Перед каждой `0A` самостоятельно прописывается символ `0D`

Мне известно, что `0A` это символ возврата каретки, а `0D` это символ переноса строки. Но мне непонятно, как он может появиться самостоятельно, ведь я работаю с числами и байтами, а не со строками.

С чем может быть связано такое поведение и как мне устранить этот баг ?

Comment: Как у вас с Русским?

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian or move it to engSO.

Comment: Извиняюсь, немного промахнулся с языковой веткой ) перевел на русский )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я полагаю, что где-то происходит сбой и файл воспринимается как текстовый и вступает в действие *system dependent* умолчания когда конец строки для Windows это комбинация `<LF><CR>`, а для Unix просто `<CR>`. Попробуйте использовать `RandomAccessFile`

Если все действительно так как вы описали - тема достойна для [публикации бага в Java](http://bugs.java.com)

Comment: Как оказалось, файл формировался корректно. Длина массива байт и длина файла совпадали. Проблема оказалась в почтовом клиенте, который при отправке сообщения "ломал" вложенный файл.